# Error when restoring a iOS 4.3.5 backup onto a iOS 5 device

Tags: iphone, backup, ios

I have tried several times with several backups, but i keep getting the message that the backup is corrupted or not compatible.

Comment: I thought that was what happened after I had to use the restore function to upgrade to iOS 5 on my iPhone and iPad. Immediately after rebooting after upgrading, it asked if I wanted to restore a backup, and then proceeded to do so.

Comment: That's what I did and it worked for me without problem (or error message)

Comment: thanks for your answers. it is strange, indeed: i keep getting the same error message!

Answer (score 1):

After the restore fails, take a look at the phone and see if your data is installed.

Restoring data after every major iOS update has failed on me, but after I put the apps back on, all my data is there.  Pick a few apps that you know contain data (Contacts, games, documents, Notes, login details) and see if your data has at least been restored.

It takes some time to put the apps and usic back on, but major iOS updates only happen once every couple of years.